# Simplifying UNION query that looks for duplicate names

Tags: postgresql

```
create table sections(
  id serial,
  section_name char(255) not null,
  version_id int not null
);

create table section_versions(
 id int primary key not null,
 version_name char(255) not null  
);

insert into section_versions(id, version_name)
values (1, 'default'), (2, 'version A'), (3, 'version B');

insert into sections(section_name, version_id)
values ('Toys', 1), ('Animals', 1), ('Cars', 1),
       ('Toys', 2), ('Animals', 2), ('Instruments', 2),
       ('Toys', 3);
```

I need to select **sections** based on requested **section_version.version_name**.

If the **version_name** is **"default"**, then query just need to return all **sections** which have **"default"** version.

But if the **"version A"** was requested, then it should return every **section** that belongs to **"version A"**, and add a missing sections from **"default"** version - basing on **section_name**.

**Please see this fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/466e1/1/0

Here's what I came up with:

```
select * from sections
join section_versions on (section_versions.id = sections.version_id)
where section_versions.version_name = 'default'

and sections.section_name not in (
  select sections.section_name from sections
  join section_versions on (section_versions.id = sections.version_id)
  where section_versions.version_name = 'version A'
)

UNION

select * from sections
join section_versions on (section_versions.id = sections.version_id)
where section_versions.version_name = 'version A'
;
```

**This is probably a naive try, so I am looking for a better solution.**

It would be nice to have one query that will handle:

1. Selecting only "default"
2. Selecting a specific version
3. Working when no default version exists (f.i. like Instruments)